# Adding set state change causes infinite loop in React

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to create an offline fuzzy search using gatsby (react) and Fuse.js and I am running into an issue storing the 'searched for' terms using setState.

I get the following error:
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I am not sure how to save the new state (code below)

```
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/index.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function(data) {
                setPosts(data.data.allContentfulPost.edges)
            })
    }, [])

    if (posts) {
        var list = posts //returns 326 items
        var options = {
            shouldSort: true,
            threshold: 0.6,
            location: 0,
            distance: 100,
            maxPatternLength: 32,
            minMatchCharLength: 1,
            keys: ["node.title", "node.meta"],
        }
        var fuse = new Fuse(list, options)
        var results = fuse.search("marketing") //returns 11 items
        setPosts(results) //causes infinite loop
    }
```

Comment: There's never a reason to add "in React" to your question title. The tag is enough.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix the problem is to use another state for filtered posts. And keep the original posts for futur use :

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/index.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            setPosts(data.data.allContentfulPost.edges)
        })
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  var options = {
      shouldSort: true,
      threshold: 0.6,
      location: 0,
      distance: 100,
      maxPatternLength: 32,
      minMatchCharLength: 1,
      keys: ["node.title", "node.meta"],
  }
  var fuse = new Fuse(posts, options)
  var results = fuse.search("marketing") //returns 11 items
  setFilteredPosts(results) 
}, [posts])
```

Answer (score 0):

Except from rare use cases you shouldn't call `setState` directly in your components render method and if you do so you need to be careful to chose the right condition to do so.

Usually this is the case if your state depends on props provided to the component. The class based component lifecycle method is called `getDerivedStateFromProps`. You don't need that here.

It looks like you are trying to narrow down the result from your API endpoint. The transformation can be done in the fetch callback before calling `setPosts`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/index.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            const allPosts = data.data.allContentfulPost.edges;
            const options = {
                shouldSort: true,
                threshold: 0.6,
                location: 0,
                distance: 100,
                maxPatternLength: 32,
                minMatchCharLength: 1,
                keys: ["node.title", "node.meta"],
            }
            const fuse = new Fuse(allPosts, options)
            const found = fuse.search("marketing")

            setPosts(found);
        })
}, [])
```